# can we copy paste an entire userform in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

On selecting one item from the list of combobox items can i be able to get an entire userform pasted below the ComboBox (For Ex: if i select userform1 from the drop down menu then entire interface of userform1 should be pasted below the combobox)

I had tried this

```
If ComboBox1.value="Userform1" Then
    UserForm1.show
ElseIf ComboBox1.Value="Userform2" Then
    UserForm2.show
End If
```

But in this userforms pops up .....I just want to get entire userform in the same design to get pasted below the ComboBox

Thanks in advance

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Xnf.png)[example image]

Comment: it can be made by this simple code, you probably need to create all components from a schratch. Because `.show` just activating whole form. Or you need to close previous form and activate new one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate User Form in Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817764/duplicate-user-form-in-excel-vba)

Comment: exactly.......i dont want to make entire userform to get activated

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. But if you are trying to show a screenshot of a userform in an Excel sheet then it's gonna get a bit tricky and you'll probably have to (1) show the form, (2) make use of `user32` to take a screenshot, (3) export the screenshot and (4) show / import it in Excel as a `JPG`. If you ask me. That's way too much work and I'd rather go with the proposal offered by @Luboš-suk and `.show` the form (possibly showing it [modeless](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251819.aspx)).

Comment: You could hide all the components inside the `Userform` and depending on which version you want active you activate those components.

Comment: in addition to DragonSamu's idea, you could create a series of form using multi-page and have the code hide or show the appropriate page according to the combo box selection.